# Why the same position u for two different functions applying mean-value theorem?

Tags: calculus

I don't know why the function in the nominator and denominator as shown in the figure (Red Arrow) has the same position u after the application of Mean Value Theorem. It is because they are not the same function, so they should have different position for their own identical slope.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

It can be the same $u$. I think that this refers implicitly to [Cauchy's mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy.27s_mean_value_theorem) (see link).

Comment: oh, it helps a lot